# Logging prop values in functional components possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to view what `props` are getting passed to my component. Is there a way to log it in JSX? I'm using 2 functional components as in the following code block.

From the invocation I'm passing `props` as `props:{programs:'Hello',locale:'en'}`. It seems the props get into the `ProgramsSummaryParent` just fine but I am getting this message on the browser when it tries to render the `ProgramsSummaryPlaceholder` :

Failed prop type: The prop `content` is marked as required in `TableCell`, but its value is `undefined`.

Why am I unable to pass the `prop`?

```
const ProgramsSummaryParent = ({programs, locale,}) => (
<BaseSummary locale={locale}>
    <ProgramsSummaryPlaceholder prg={programs}/>
</BaseSummary>
);

const ProgramsSummaryPlaceholder = ({ prg, intl, }) => (
<div className="programs-summary">      
  <Table isStriped={true} isPadded={true}>
   <Table.Rows >
      <Table.Row >
        <Table.Cell content={prg.programs} />
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Rows>
  </Table>
</div>
);
```

Comment: If you have your child component return a block you can add arbitrary statements include a `console.log`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen How do I return a block? I tried putting it within { } but that didn't work.

Comment: I added an example below.

Comment: is it possible you meant to pass just `content={prg}` to `Table.Cell`?

Comment: @TuriS. so I'm new to the whole thing but aren't `props` passed as key=value and accessed as `props.key`? I was hoping for something similar here. `programs` is just the key and its value is the one I'm interested in.

Comment: Yes. So in ProgramsSummaryPlaceholder, the variable `prg` (really `props.prg`) is the same value as `programs` from the parent component. Then you are passing `prg.programs` (`programs.programs` in the parent context) to TableCell

Comment: The error is essentially saying that there is no property `programs.programs`, so I was just wondering if you meant to pass `programs` (`prg`) itself

Comment: @TuriS. I get the same error in the browser's console even when I pass {prg} to Table.Cell content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your child component to return a block, then you can add arbitrary statements for debugging:

```
const ProgramsSummaryPlaceholder = ({ prg, intl, }) => {
  console.log({ prg, intl });
  return (
    <div className="programs-summary">      
      <Table isStriped={true} isPadded={true}>
        <Table.Rows >
          <Table.Row >
            <Table.Cell content={prg.programs} />
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Rows>
     </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you are done debugging, just change it back into returning just the JSX.

Comment: could be because Programs is undefined

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri So I am passing `programs` as Hello in the above example. Why would it be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Use [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) browser extension.

After installing the extension you can open the developer tool and select React tab. There you will see all your components and you can select the component you want and see `state` and `props` it receives in the right-side pane.

Comment: That doesn't show the `prg` prop which I'm passing to `ProgramsSummaryPlaceholder`. It just shows `intl`.